# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake. After restarting the server it works fine, but it shows up again

Tags: java, ssl

I am getting this SSLHandshakeException in my weblogic application logs when trying to connect to an endpoint using TLSv1.2. After restarting the server I don't see the exception and it works fine, but it shows up again after sometime. 
Below are the details -

```
Java Version in weblogic servers : java version "1.7.0_80"
Arguments in server start : -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
Certificates are added in cacerts and trust.jks
Remote host is accepting only TLSv1.2
Property has been set : TLS_VERSION=TLSv1.2
```

Kindly assist me with this and let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: can you show the detailed exception stacktrace?

Comment: (1) @Manmohan_singh: the stacktrace will only show that we're in handshake code which won't likely help; OP: if you can run with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` and capture the output around the problem that may help, but is likely to be large; or else try for a net capture like tcpdump  (2) `jdk.tls.client.protocols` doesn't exist in j7, at least non-paid j7 including 7u80; `https.protocols` does but only matters if your code is using `(Https)URLConnection`, either directly or via a library -- do you know it is?

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085,if I enable debug ssl in server start arguments, I'll have to start the server which will resolve the issue. Still let me check. I am from Ops team, I need to check with Dev Team what code they are using.

Comment: Below is the code from HeaderType.class
`stub.setHeader("java:com.comcast.types", "RequestHeader", header);
    try
    {
      ApplicationLogger.info("Exiting STUB - Setting SSLContext Values");
      String tlsVersion = this.prop.getProperty("TLS_VERSION");
      ApplicationLogger.info("TLS version :::  " + tlsVersion);
      SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance(tlsVersion);
      ctx.init(null, null, null);
      SSLContext.setDefault(ctx);
    }`

Comment: An external capture, like tcpdump or wireshark, is enough to determine if the problem is version (not being 1.2) or something else, which at least narrows the scope of your search or testing some. It's better to add your code to the Q where it can be formatted -- and _won't_ be deleted by cleanup; but changing the default context does not necessarily affect individual connections depending on the code that does the connection(s).

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085for your inputs. The issue still persists. We are digging in deep to check further.